# Show Model Validation Progress with Keras model.fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a CNN model using `tf.keras` passing training and validation generators as follows:

```
model.fit(
    x=training_data_generator,
    validation_data=validation_data_generator,
    epochs=n_epochs,
    use_multiprocessing=False,
    max_queue_size=100,
    workers=50
)
```

The generators are based on `tf.keras.Sequence`.

The problem is, my data set is huge. Training one epoch takes about a day (despite training on two Titan RTX GPUs) and validation after each epoch takes a few hours.

During training I can see the progress displayed, but during validation all I see is the last snapshot of the training progress bar:

`130339/130340 [==============================] - 147432s 1s/step`

until the validation finishes and finally I see my validation acuracy, loss etc.

*Is there a way to display a progress bar for validation?*

I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    model.fit(
        x=training_data_generator,
        epochs=1,
        use_multiprocessing=False,
        max_queue_size=100,
        workers=50
    )
    validation_results = model.evaluate(
        x=validation_data_generator,
        use_multiprocessing=False,
        max_queue_size=100,
        workers=50
    )
    print(validation_results)
```

Another option I was considering is to create a custom callback that validates the model `on_epoch_end`, but this seems very non-standard.

Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: I'm afraid the only thing that I could propose is to add `initial_epoch=epoch+1` to your `model.fit()` (especially useful if you're logging to Tensorboard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a **steps_per_epoch** on the fit method.

Based on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model): 
*Total number of steps (batches of samples) before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch. When training with input tensors such as TensorFlow data tensors, 
the default None is equal to the number of samples in your dataset divided by the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined. If x is a tf.data dataset, and 'steps_per_epoch' is None, the epoch will run until the input dataset is exhausted. This argument is not supported with array inputs.*

By this, you can limit the per epoch steps, so setting it with a lower value will immediately give you the **validation loss & accuracy per epoch** 
By setting the steps_per_epoch to a lower size means you need to increase the epoch.

Every 1000 steps or epoch, it will show you the **training and validation loss & accuracy** after finishing 1000 steps rather than exhausting the entire dataset first then showing the results.

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=2,
                    epochs=30,
                    steps_per_epoch=1000,
                    # We pass some validation for
                    # monitoring validation loss and metrics
                    # at the end of each epoch
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Comment: And if we just want a progress bar without changing steps_per_epoch ?
I don't understand why there is a progress bar for training but not for validation (in TF2.1).

Comment: Remember to set verbose to 1 when calling fit. From the docs: 0 = silent, 1 = progress bar, 2 = one line per epoch. Note that the progress bar is not particularly useful when logged to a file, so verbose=2 is recommended when not running interactively (eg, in a production environment).

Comment: With `verbose=1`, nothing is printed during the comparison with validation data (`tensorflow==2.4.4`).  There's a relevant issue [Update Progressbar During Validation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13527)